# Split java strings in Rhino

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I'm trying to split a java string in a Rhino javascript program

```
var s = new java.lang.String("1 2 3");
s.split();
```

which give me the error

```
js: Can't find method java.lang.String.split().
```

The Rhino docs mentioned that all the javascript String.prototype methods (like match, split, etc.) are available on java string if they're not already provided by java.lang.String. Any ideas on what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Java docs: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Doesn't seem to be a 0 parameter constructor for the split method.  You gotta pass it a regular expression.

Also, for further clarification, the split method returns a string array, it's not a void method like the way you've used it in your sample code.

Answer (score 2):

split takes an argument, which is the regular expression you want to use to split your tokens.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 2):

Rhino provides only the methods that `java.lang.String` is missing and [`split`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) obviously isn't one of them.

In order to use JavaScript's implementation of `split`, you'll have to convert Java string to JavaScript one:

```js
var s = String(new java.lang.String("1 2 3"));
// Also valid: var s = "" + new java.lang.String("1 2 3");
print(s.split()); // 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the same context, but may help someone.

I use the JavaScript function split() in Rhino.

To get things working, I follow the pattern :

```
var l_VAR = "" + some_function();
var l_VARs = l_VAR.split("%%");
```

I suppose that "" + forces Rhino to use a JavaScript type of String.

When I forget to add "" + then I got the message

```
TypeError: split is not a function.
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you're using it incorrectly.
Doesn't split require a string parameter?